# Save StdOut and StdErr to two different files and append them in third one

Tags: windows, shell, pipe

I would like to save result of my script run with `sh.exe` on windows into three different files:
stdout to `stdout.txt`; stderr to `stderr.txt` and append stdout and stderr to `all.txt`. I tried to use

```
foo.sh &> all.txt 2> stderr.txt
```

or

```
foo.sh 2>&1 1>logfile | tee -a logfile
```

but it doen't even append stderr and stdout.

How can I do it?

Comment: Windows or Linux? Remove the Linux tag if your question had nothing to do with Linux OS.

Comment: Why not `>stdout.txt 2>stderr.txt` and then `copy stdout.txt+stderr.txt all.txt` ?

Comment: Because I want to have error after execute command